# How to use OpenJPA EntityManagerFactory in JSF

Tags: jsf, jpa, entitymanager

I use OpenJPA on WebSphere Application Server.
My WebApplication uses JSF 2 (without EJB).

I wanted to know if there are best practices how to use JPA in JSF.

I found that the EntityManagerFactory (EMF) should be application scoped.
Also the EMF should be (only) destroyed when the application stops.

But my sources are not the newest:

[Java Notepad: JPA EMF in web applications](http://javanotepad.blogspot.de/2007/05/jpa-entitymanagerfactory-in-web.html) from 2007

[Best way to use JPA in web-tier](http://www.swview.org/blog/best-way-use-jpa-web-tier) from 2010

[How to close a JPA EntityManger in web applications](http://javanotepad.blogspot.de/2007/06/how-to-close-jpa-entitymanger-in-web.html)
 from 2007

Are there other practices or better ways to handle JPA in JSF?
Especially Scope of EMF and DAO.

Best Regards, Veote

Comment: Do you use a framework like Spring or CDI?

Comment: No, I dont use such a Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which creates the EMF in `init()` method, closes it in `destroy()` method and creates an `EntityManager` in `doFilter()` method which get set as a `ThreadLocal<EntityManager>`. You can also begin and end the transactions in there.

This is also known as the "open session in view" or "open entitymanager in view" pattern.